How to translate "soweit ihnen zu folgen war"?
I came across the following sentence in a text about a process of some criminals:

Diese Feststellungen beruhen auf den Einlassungen der Angeklagten Hamann, Bornholt und Lab., soweit ihnen zu folgen war, sowie auf der Befragung der Zeugen Aft., Ga. (...).

Could someone tell me how to correctly and precisely translate the bolded phrase ("soweit ihnen zu folgen war")? 
When I've googled for it I found only three results - all in the same context...

"soweit" = "insofar as"
"ihnen folgen" could either mean "understand" (i.e. some of the defendants' statements were so incoherent as to be unintelligible) or "trustworthy" (i.e. their statements were partially refuted or deemed unlikely).
"[thing] ist zu [verb]" means that it verb is the thing to do to thing. Without context, we can't tell you whether that means "the law requires that we do this", or "any decent person would do this", or "this seems the only logically possible option".
